# configure Git to accept a particular self-signed server certificate for a particular https remote

Tags: git, ssl-certificate

The sysadmin for a project I'm on has decided that SSH is "too much trouble"; instead, he has set up Git to be accessible via an `https://` URL (and username/password authentication). The server for this URL presents a self-signed certificate, so he advised everyone to turn off certificate validation. This does not strike me as a good setup, security-wise.

Is it possible to tell Git that for remote X (or better, any remote in any repository that happens to begin with `https://$SERVERNAME/`) it is to accept a particular certificate, and *only* that certificate?  Basically reduplicate SSH's server-key behavior.

Comment: You are asking about C Git on Unix, i presume?

Comment: Yah.  Well, conceivably also Windows, but nobody's doing that right now.

Comment: WTF? @Zack you are absolute right about the certificate checks. When your admin says you should turn off certificate checks, he can also turn off TLS on the server, since then every one is disabling the protection against a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: @Rudi, is this still the case if they use an IP address to access the server? (It seems the DNS lookup is how MITM gets inbetween so I think IP address should be immune to this.)

Comment: @Chris Yes, it is still the case.  A MITM router can pretend to be any IP address they want.  (You know those interstitial pages you get on the free wifi in the airport?  Those are MITMs.  Try accessing a page by IP address sometime.)

Answer (score 414, accepted):

Briefly:

1. Get the self signed certificate
2. Put it into some (e.g. `~/git-certs/cert.pem`) file
3. Set `git` to trust this certificate using `http.sslCAInfo` parameter

In more details:

## Get self signed certificate of remote server

Assuming, the server URL is `repos.sample.com` and you want to access it over port `443`.

There are multiple options, how to get it.

### Get certificate using openssl

```
$ openssl s_client -connect repos.sample.com:443
```

Catch the output into a file `cert.pem` and delete all but part between (and including) `-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-` and `-END CERTIFICATE-`

Content of resulting file ~/git-certs/cert.pem may look like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

### Get certificate using your web browser

I use Redmine with Git repositories and I access the same URL for web UI and for git command line access. This way, I had to add exception for that domain into my web browser.

Using Firefox, I went to `Options -> Advanced -> Certificates -> View Certificates -> Servers`, found there the self-signed host, selected it and using `Export` button I got exactly the same file, as created using `openssl`.

Note: I was a bit surprised, there is no name of the authority visibly mentioned. This is fine.

## Having the trusted certificate in dedicated file

Previous steps shall result in having the certificate in some file. It does not matter, what file it is as long as it is visible to your git when accessing that domain. I used `~/git-certs/cert.pem`

Note: If you need more trusted self-signed certificates, put them into the same file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDnzCCAocCBE/xnXAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgZMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMRUw
...........
/27/jIdVQIKvHok2P/u9tvTUQA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
AnOtHeRtRuStEdCeRtIfIcAtEgOeShErExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxw
...........
/27/jIdVQIKvHok2P/u9tvTUQA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This should work (but I tested it only with single certificate).

## Configure git to trust this certificate

```
$ git config --global http.sslCAInfo /home/javl/git-certs/cert.pem
```

You may also try to do that system wide, using `--system` instead of `--global`.

Test it. You should now be able to communicate with your server without resorting to:

```
$ git config --global http.sslVerify false # NO NEED TO USE THIS
```

If you already set your git to ignore ssl certificates, unset that:

```
$ git config --global --unset http.sslVerify
```

You may also check that you did it all correctly, without spelling errors:

```
$ git config --global --list
```

That should list all variables, you have set globally.

Comment: i think that this answer is more correct and complete than the accepted one. thank you @Jan Vlcinsky

Comment: After that the usual authority-signed certificates stop working, so I can't pull e.g. from Github. Is there a way to add a self-signed certificate without turning off the authority signed ones?

Comment: On OSX 10.9 (Git 1.8.5.2 Apple Git-48) this doesn't seem to work. It looks like Git is ignoring sslCAInfo and the environment variable GIT_SSL_CAINFO.

However it is possible to add the generated cert.pem to the OSX Key Ring Application (system keyring) and to set the trust level to always. Git will happily accept the self signed certificate after that.

Comment: @peter_gent As I do not have access to OSX (working on Ubuntu 14.04), I cannot serve with testing on OSX. The only think I can do is to review the solution on Ubuntu, git is in time slowly evolving and some things could have change a bit. Hope to find a time for this within next week.

Comment: is there a way to reconfigure git back to default settings ?

Comment: @MichaelIvko solution that takes into account 'usual authority-signed certificates' descried here (you need to add your certificate to 'curl-ca-bundle.crt' file): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exe-s-store.aspx

Comment: If you do not want to add the certificate globally, and you must first clone the repo, you can also use a environment variable for cloning. 
After cloning, you can add the configuration described above to add the key.
# GIT_SSL_CAINFO=yourserver.pem git clone https://YOURSERVER.../

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it effectively removes all the default CAs that come with git (eg after doing this, you won't be able to pull from github).  Most likely that's not what most are looking for.  A better example is to add the new root CA to a copy of Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt, and then reference the new copy of curl-ca-bundle.crt from your gitconfig.

Comment: so git doesn't use the default ssl certificate location such as

/etc/ssl/certs?

Comment: it does work on windows! export every cert in the certificate-chain as Base64 coded X.509 file (.CER) Put all the files together and reference this file. Be sure that you don't have spaces in the path to the cert file (use oldschool paths)

Comment: I like the #NO NEED TO USE THIS line :) Useful for quick n dirty git clone

Comment: The fetching part can be easily taken care of in a single command: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.example:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM >>~/git-certs/cert.pem` but note that using s_client will only work with self-signed certificates(?). I spent way too much time figuring out that there was a separate CA in my case which simply doesn't get spit out by the server.

Comment: I tried this, however the following was the only thing that worked for me:
https://tnckb94959.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/10845i3A3E82A75060430C/image-dimensions/2500?v=1.0&px=-1

Comment: I found that using `--system` did not work, but using `--global` did.

Comment: To not disable all default/system CAs for all domains but only for this one domain use instead: `git config --global http."https://repos.sample.com".sslCAInfo /home/javl/git-certs/cert.pem` and if there are any http urls that get redirected additionally also `git config --global http."http://redirect-source.example.com".sslCAInfo /home/javl/git-certs/cert.pem`

Answer (score 9):

OSX User adjustments.

Following the steps of the Accepted answer worked for me with a small addition when configuring on OSX.

I put the `cert.pem` file in a directory under my OSX logged in user and thus caused me to adjust the location for the trusted certificate.

Configure git to trust this certificate:

```
$ git config --global http.sslCAInfo $HOME/git-certs/cert.pem
```