# Can not clone git repo to server

Tags: git, gitweb

I'm running the same command on 2 different servers.  One works, the other doesn't.

I'm running
git clone https://blah.com:8443/blah.git

On server A, it works fine.  I get the objects, files, etc. no problems.

On server B, I get the following message.

```
git clone https://blah.com:8443/blah.git
Cloning into 'blah'...
error: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates while accessing https://blah.com:8443/blah.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Does anyone know what this means or what I need to do to get this to work?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Is server B using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @cjc343, i'm sorry but i'm not sure.  i didn't set up the machines.  how can i tell/check?  and actually, server A is my laptop.  server B is a real server.  server B is running centos.  the laptop is running OSX.

Comment: Chances are it is. Per the second method (ignoring certs) you can run `git config http.sslVerify false` in the problematic repo, test if it works, and if it does, I would recommend you then follow the steps in the answer covering properly trusting the cert, including finishing with `git config http.sslVerify true` or `git config --unset http.sslVerify` to close the security hole that disabling verification opens.

Comment: @cjc343 holy moly, thx.  the 2nd method worked...sort of.  it didn't work with the `git config http.sslVerify true` but it worked with `export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true`, which it alluded to.  thx for your help, and the warning.  I'll look at the first method later.  my brain is fried now  =)  thx again for un-frying my brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376) is a question covering trusting a self-signed certificate. This is the proper way to fix the issue assuming you are using a self-signed cert.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768) question covers ignoring a certificate, however, depending on which method you use, this could result in ignoring all certificates, which would make communicating with your git server insecure, and is therefore a quick solution, but not a good solution. If you take this route, I would recommend at least using the per-repository setting (`git config http.sslVerify false`) instead of applying it more broadly in order to minimize the severe negative impact of this method.