# executing 'brew tap homebrew/science' : error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: homebrew

I want to install octave for the coursera machine learning course. However, I'm running into some problems when I try to use

'brew tap homebrew/science'

This results in the following error from the shell:

```
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/': SSL certificate  problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

How can I fix/resolve this issue ? More specifically what command will reset the path for ssl certificates to the keychain?

edit:

this is an unintended bug/problem that is directly related to the solution for this SO post : [configure Git to accept a particular self-signed server certificate for a particular https remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic)

Answer (score 0):

I fix it adjusting the date/time of my computer. The time was incorrect and all certifies was invalid.