# How to solve Intellij Git error Empty reply from server

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I do a Git fetch or a Git push from within Intellij, the error message **".....  Empty reply from server"** appears.  When doing a "Git Fetch origin" from the command line, no error message appears.
The remote repository is defined in Intellij.
What could be the cause that Intellij doesn't recognise the remote repository

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try the solutions described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364023/gits-error-on-push-empty-reply-from-server

Comment: The solutions don't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem with the following settings in Intellij :

[image]