# Project push error

Tags: git, android-studio, github

Hi am new to `github` and `bitbucket`

I am trying to use this for my android studio
first i create project and create repository in the github, then I follow all the step to push the project. but i get error when push the project 
error is:

> Push failed
>   Failed with error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Harin-Kaklotar/ProjectWithNewBoston.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8087: Connection refused
>   [image]
>   how to solve this?

I am using windows os
I use this example https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/#comment-23697

can any one help to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "git pull,fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com...\': Empty reply from server"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087483/how-to-resolve-git-pull-fatal-unable-to-access-https-github-com-empty)

Comment: I just see only one repository in your github at link https://github.com/Harin-Kaklotar/ProjectWithNewBoston. So you should use link: https://github.com/Harin-Kaklotar/ProjectWithNewBoston.git

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon I change this but i got same error

Comment: Is `internet connection` there?

Comment: @Arpit yes I have internet connection

Comment: Try pushing the repository from command line, might be Android Studio not able to access github.

Comment: @Arpit I also try this one. I used git Bash also

Comment: Forget Android Studio, Vote for git bash. Please show us what did you typed in Git Bash.

Comment: git remote add origin https://github.com/Harin-Kaklotar/ProjectWithNewBoston.git    git push origin master

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the steps below:

```
# add remote for local directory
git remote add origin https://github.com/Harin-Kaklotar/ProjectWithNewBoston.git

# add all file to stage
git add -A

# commit your code 
git commit -m 'first commit'

# pull to update the changes from remote
git pull origin master

# push to remote
git push origin master
```

Comment to me if you have any issue.

Comment: Did you try open "Git Bash" as Administrator?

Comment: yes, but it's not work. I think your code is perfect but this is error is about proxy and port setting related.

Comment: I think you should use the latest Git Bash version, and try to ping github.com from your Git Bash