# Unable to access repo in Azure Devops

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am new to Azure Devops, when I tried to navigate the repository URL in Browser I can able to do so (edit and create branches in browser), but when I am trying to clone it in my local machine using Visual studio and git bash, I am facing the following error

> git failed with a fatal error unable to access 'my url' Empty reply from server

Comment: What have you searched and tried? And the result is? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087483/how-to-resolve-git-pull-fatal-unable-to-access-https-github-com-empty/27352176#27352176