# SSL certificate validate fails

Tags: git, bash, ssl

I am trying to use Git Bash to pull code frm stash. After I made:

`$ git clone http://source/code/address.git`

The bash terminal gives me error message:

> SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Then I added the SSL certificate into the config file according to the higest voted answer: ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic)))

And I check the config list:

```
git config --global --list
```

then I got:

> http.sslcainfo=c:/Users/lyang/Git/git-certs/cert.pem
>
> push.default=upstream

Which means I've already set the SSL certificate as trusted, but when I tried to clone again, the original error message shows again:

> SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

I am wondering why it happens and how I can sove it.

Thanks

Comment: while not directly relevant to your question - using ssh://source.code/address.git might turn out to be safer