# JGit Clone Repo kicked off from windows task manager fails

Tags: clone, jgit, windows-task-scheduler

Lets start by saying my code works. I can click a batch file that runs a jar file,  that downloads some code from GIT.

```
Git gitRepo = Git.cloneRepository().setURI( remoteProjectPath )
.setDirectory(new File(destination))
.setCredentialsProvider( new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( repoUser, repoPassword ) )
.setBranch(branch)
.setNoCheckout(true)
.call();
```

In windows, in my user profile folder i have a .gitconfig file that contains:

```
[http]
sslverify = false
```

when I double click the batch file, it works.
But, this is part of an automated process.  i need windows task scheduler to execute the batch file at midnight. (time is not important, other than it's when i'm not at work.)
But i can open the task scheduler and click on the task and click 'run' and it fails with the sslverify flag.

> "Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

it appears to me that the .gitconfig is only used when I (manually) execute the process. Is there a way to figure out if JGit is attempting to read from a different dir when started by task scheduler?
Or is there another way to make JGit use sslverify=false for a sparse checkout using CloneCommand?

Comment: JGit's CloneCommand can't skip SSL verification, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998477/set-ssl-verification-off-for-jgit-clone-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a reference to EGit I found: [How to change "Location" for "User Settings"](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/598634/)

I went to the system environment variables and created a system variable 'HOME' and set it to a directory containing the .gitconfig file I needed, and now the process works even when kicked off from Windows task scheduler.