# Include StrictHostKeyChecking in JGit to clone a git repo

Tags: java, git, ssh, jgit

I am using JGit to clone a remote git repo as:

> Git.cloneRepository().setURI("ssh://krisv@10.1.5.32:8001/myrepo").setDirectory(gitDir).setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();

However, when I do so, it gives me the following error:

> org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: ssh://user@10.1.9.1:8001: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialItem$YesNoType:The authenticity of host '10.1.9.1' can't be established.
>   DSA key fingerprint is "some value".
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting?

Now I don't want this message to prompt and I want to bypass this by providing **Yes** by default. However, I am not getting any such option in JGit.

There is an option in ssh: **StrictHostKeyChecking** with which we can bypass this. Is there any way by which we can use this option in JGit? Or any other way to achieve the same?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998477/set-ssl-verification-off-for-jgit-clone-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn SSL verification off for JGit clone command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998477/turn-ssl-verification-off-for-jgit-clone-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I was able to get this working. I added the following code and it worked:

> JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");