# How to disable Jenkins checkout and git plugin SSL verify?

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins, jgit

I'm running Jenkins agent in K8s nodes.
I add `git config --global http.sslVerify false` in dockerfile. I also add `~/.gitconfig` in dockerfile too.
I try to use Jenkins `checkout` and `git` in pipeline to fetch codes, but I got following error:

```
 stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ops.prod.hccn/iac/gitops/vsphere_linux.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

But if I replace them by `sh git clone` command, it's ok.

So here are my questions:

1. `git config --global http.sslVerify false` is only works for `git` command, don't work for Jenkins `checkout` and `git`, right? Because `git` command is a sh command, but Jenkins `checkout` `git` is some kind of Java plugin?
2. Is Jenkins `checkout` also reference `git` or `gitclient` plugin?
3. How to disable Jenkins `checkout` and `git` plugin SSL verify? I don't find them on [jenkins git-client plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-client/) or [jenkins git plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) or [jenkins scm plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-scm-step/)

Supplement：

1. I run `git config --global http.sslVerify false` on each k8s node
2. Jenkins Version is 2.277.4
3. Jenkins Git Plugin Version is 4.7.1
4. Jenkins Git Client Plugin Version is 3.7.1

Supplement 2:

I have **2 git project**. The `Jenkinsfile` is in the first one, which configure in the Jenkins Job. The default checkout is working well. During the pipeline running, it will try to pull **another git project on the Jenkins agent**, this is where the problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Jenkins Git client plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-client), I would avoid JGit (set in [this setting](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-client/#jgit))

[image: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin@master/images/enable-jgit.png]

I would:

- select Git
- Make sure `git` is in the `$PATH` of the Jenkins Controller (formerly known as "master")

Then the global setting `http.sslVerify` would be enforced.
Although, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35587504/6309), JGit should also be able to read the same setting.

From [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939390/how-to-disable-jenkins-checkout-and-git-plugin-ssl-verify/69939927#comment123686843_69939927)/[discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239262/discussion-between-bryan-chen-and-vonc), the [OP Bryan Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7103358/bryan-chen) adds:

> I have two git project.
> The Jenkinsfile is in the first one, which configure in the Jenkins Job. The default checkout is working well.
> During the pipeline running, it will try to pull another git project on the Jenkins agent, this is where the problem arises.

That means the root cause seems to be within the container executing the job as an agent (in a container), not in the main Jenkins controller.

Comment: Hello, @VonC. My current git selection is `git`, `.gitconfig` location is /root/ and it has taken effect. I can see it by `git config --list`,and Jenkins progress UID is root. At the same time, I run `git config --list` in the docker(Jenkins agent in K8s node), it's take effect too.  As I mentioned, `sh git` is ok but Jenkins `checkout` and `git` function are not.

Comment: @BryanChen Then double-check with which account the Jenkins controller is running, and try to make a job executed on the controller, with a simple script step `git config --global -l`

Comment: Hello @Vonc, Here is the command output: `ps -ef | grep jenkins`: `root  2362   1  0 Nov04 ?        00:46:46 /etc/alternatives/java ........Omit some parameters`. Git config is has taken effect: `git config --global -l`: `http.sslverify=false`

Comment: Here is full output:
`root        2362       1  0 Nov04 ?        00:46:46 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Xmx4096m -Dorg.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator.websocketConnectionTimeout=60 -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=9080 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
`

Comment: @BryanChen Why running Jenkins as root though? This is usually a cause for reading the wrong global Git config.

Comment: Hello @Vonc, I compare of my Jenkins config and origin Jenkins config from rpm. The different is only Jenkins user, port and JVM params. Sadly I change user back to jenkins, restart jenkins and then test, same result…

Comment: @BryanChen That is why doing a test job with in it a `sh` step `git config --global -l; pwd; id -a` would help.

Comment: Hello @VonC, here is the script brief output: `git config --global -l`: `http.sslverify=false` ... `whoami`: `root`... `cat /root/.gitconfig`: `[http] sslVerify =false`. (There is no `id -a` in the docker) I'm afriad `root` is defined in the dockerfile(or omitted as `root`). If I change Jenkins agent `root` to `jenkins`, I'm afriad I had to rewrite a lot of code because in fact there is terraform rely on root default terraform settings.

Comment: @BryanChen Root inside a docker container is not surprising. But keep in mind, the checkout is generally done on the Jenkins controller, not on the agent. Was you test job executed on the main controller?

Comment: I have agent statement, at the begainning of pipeline. So checkout step is actually run on the specific agent. I don't write a real pipeline to test on the jenkins master, but by way of the snippet generator, after I chose the correct credential, it shows no error. So I suppose Jenkins master is ok.

Comment: Hello @VonC, I think you misunderstanding something: I have **2 git project**. The `Jenkinsfile` is in the first one, which configure in the Jenkins Job. The default checkout is working well. During the pipeline running, it will try to pull another git project on the Jenkins agent, this is where the problem arises.

Comment: @BryanChen OK. That wasn't clear from your original question, indeed. In the docker container, JGit or "Jenkins Git client" is not a factor at all. Only the local GIt installed in the container is.

Comment: So it is very weird that `git config --global` doesn't make any sense, right?

Comment: @BryanChen Yes, if it is done inside the container.

Comment: @Hello VonC, And one more thing I want to make sure. Jenkins `checkout` and `git` actually invoke `git` command, right? Perhaps this is a bug…

Comment: @BryanChen Yes. But in your case, the issue seems to be within the container executing the job as an agent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239262/discussion-between-bryan-chen-and-vonc).