# Git - Unnable to add host_key from terminal

Tags: git, rsa

Trying to push to git and it asks if I want to add the fingerprint key to the cache I get this message:

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 44:2d:5b:28:f4:f6:30:df:f9:64:7a:e3:92:cb:75:f2
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n)
```

When I type y then press enter nothing happens. How do I fix this problem? I tried reinstalling.

Comment: You either need to add this server's certificate into your truststore or you can configure Git to trust all certificates.

Comment: [This SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic) may be of help to you.