# How to get Git accept my self signed SSL certificate?

Tags: git, ssl

My Git installation refueses hard to `git clone` a repo due to a

`fatal: unable to access 'https://X.X.X.X/svn/...': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

error.

This is a common question around the Web, answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic). The solution consists of

1) either appending the certificate to the end of the `cert-bundle` file, or providing it as a solo file

2) making sure that the git config `http.sslCAInfo` property is pointed to the correct location in the correct config file.

On the account of finding which config file that is, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to) and [here](https://www.onwebsecurity.com/windows/git-on-windows-location-of-global-configuration-file) is where to look.

All configs listed in `git config --list --show-origin` point to the right `cert-bundle`, which of course contains the right key.

Any thoughts on **what else can break the certificate validation process?**
The error message suggests that Git (or the lib doing the job) wasn't even able to *get* the certificate. Any thoughts on how's that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

When I want to interact with something that is going to use a self signed certificate, I just ask git to not care for it. It can be configured (I think) at the repo level (or even at the global level) but I'd rather do it on the commands like fetch so that I'm always aware of what's happening. `git -c http.sslVerify=false fetch`. That should do.

Comment: by extension ```git -c http.sslVerify=false clone blahblah```

Comment: Thanks @Edmundo, I'm aware of the possibility to disable SSL verification. Actually that's the workaround I'm currently using. I'd like to solve the issue though. It'd be nice to convince Git to accept that certificate and keep SSL on...