# R studio project from Git repository, self signed certificate issue

Tags: r, git, ssl, rstudio

When I try to create a new project in R studio by cloning a repository as follows:

File >> New Project >> Version Control >> Git >> ..enter Repository URL

I get the following error message

Cloning into 'simple-repository'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/kedemd/simple-repository/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Any idea why I get this/ how to fix it?

I am using R 4.2, RStudio 1.1, and Windows

Comment: Are you behind a proxy at work/school? That error is indicative of either hitting an intermediary like that.

Comment: Yes behind a proxy a work. Do you know of any way around this without changing anything involving the proxy?

Comment: If you can install GitHub Desktop then I believe it honors proxy configurations.  There's also potentially this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure git to trust your corporate self-signed certificate.

The way to do it is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic). In substance:

1) Get the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -connect repos.sample.com:443
```

> Catch the output into a file cert.pem and delete all but part between (and including) -BEGIN CERTIFICATE- and -END CERTIFICATE-

2) Configure git to trust this certificate

```
git config --global http.sslCAInfo /path/to/cert.pem
```

Read the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic) for full details.