# How to run git clone from docker file requiring SSL certificate

Tags: git, docker, ssl, alpine-linux

I have the following code in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine/git as clone 
WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I actually have a local git and I can't disable SSL certificate.

Comment: You can download the certificate and accept it via git config or you can disable SSLVerify (which should be the last way out, because of potential MITM attacks). You can also set sslverify to false with `git -c http.sslVerify=false cmd` to each command using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [configure Git to accept a particular self-signed server certificate for a particular https remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+SSL+certificate+problem%3A+self+signed+certificate+in+certificate+chain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try and add to your Dockerfile, *before* the `git clone`:

```
RUN apk add --update \
       ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates
```

From there, as commented, you can clone the repo with an HTTPS URL like:

```
https://username:password@some.company.com/project_name.git
```

Comment: Thank you. What are the commands for alpine Linux? apt-get is not available for alpine.

Comment: @aQ123 Try `apk add --no-cache`. See example: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md#example

Comment: My file looks now like this but I'm getting this error: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  
FROM alpine/git
  
RUN apk add --update \
       ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone git@github.com:spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git

Comment: Try and use the https URL for cloning the repository

Comment: I tried with https and even added GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true but I'm getting this error: fatal: could not read Password for 'https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git': No such device or address

Comment: I was able to solve it by providing this https url: https://username:password@some.company.com/project_name.git