# Can't clone the git repo with local folder

Tags: git, ssl-certificate

When using `git clone` command (`git clone <repo url>`) this error is there:

> SSL Certification problem:self signed certificate in certificate chain

So can't clone the git repo to local folder

Comment: It may help to check the similar issue https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/unable-to-clone-git-repository-due-to-self-signed-certificate-376838977.html

Comment: Is SSL the only way to connect with that repo? Maybe HTTPS is an option?Are you trying to clone some publicly available repo? If yes, what is the url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [configure Git to accept a particular self-signed server certificate for a particular https remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+SSL+Certification+problem%3A+self+signed+certificate+in+certificate+chain

Answer (score -1):

Need to login account git (github/gitlab/etc) from cmd.

Comment: I have set up username and email address. but still same error. how do i login for git from cmd. what is the command for that?