# SSL certificate problem when trying to pull from gitlab repository

Tags: git, ssl, ssh, gitlab, ssl-certificate

i'm trying to work with an Gitlab repository of my Company. When I logged in and set up evrythin i had to generate an SSH Key to get access to the repo.

I did this as assual with this guidance: [https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#:~:text=To%20use%20SSH%20with%20GitLab%2C%20copy%20your%20public,Workstation.%208%20Optional.%20...%209%20Select%20Add%20key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#:%7E:text=To%20use%20SSH%20with%20GitLab%2C%20copy%20your%20public,Workstation.%208%20Optional.%20...%209%20Select%20Add%20key).

I also think that worked. Now my ssh keys are located in the .ssh Folder in the Home directory of the System. If i try to push the Project via the GitBash i'm getting this Error.

SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

Obviously the Error says that there is an local SSL certificate missing, but i don't know where this certificate should be located. Can anyone help me.

I also don't know if this is overall connected with the SSH key or if this topics are completely different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543283/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+SSL+certificate+problem%3A+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate

Comment: You probably cloned the repository using the https method and not the ssh method, which means now when you push `git` uses `https` so everything has to work properly at that level. Try switching to the `ssh` transport instead.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, check your remote URL

```bash
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

If it starts with `https://`: `git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:you/yourRepo`

And check your SSH key works with:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com
```

You should receive a `Welcome to GitLab, @username!` message.